# How to use devicectl appIcon command to extract iOS app icon?

Tags: ios, command-line

I'm trying to use the appIcon command of devicectl. I'm connecting to an iPhone 14 Pro running iOS 17.0.2.

```
OVERVIEW: Request app icon generation from this device.

This command searches for an app installed on this device and requests for its icon to be generated.

USAGE: devicectl device info appIcon [<options>] --device <uuid|ecid|udid|name> --allow-placeholder <allow placeholder> --width <width> --height <height> --scale <scale>

DEVICE OPTIONS:
  -d, --device <uuid|ecid|udid|name>
                          The identifier, ECID, UDID, or name of the device.

COMMAND OPTIONS:
  --app-bundle-id <app bundle identifier>
                          Look for app icon information with the given application bundle identifier on device.
        Note: If both app-bundle-id and app-path are provided, only app-path will be used.
  --app-path <app path>   Look for app icon information at the given application path on device.
        Note: If both app-bundle-id and app-path are provided, only app-path will be used.
  --allow-placeholder <allow placeholder>
                          Allow placeholder icons to be generated.
        Note: Passing `true` will allow placeholder icons to be returned. Allowing placeholder icons will ensure no I/O is done on device. If you want to make sure you get the icon
        most accurate to your request -- which could use more resources on the device -- set this to `false`.
  --width <width>         Request app icon generation with the specified width.
  --height <height>       Request app icon generation with the specified height.
  --scale <scale>         Request app icon generation with the specified scale.
  --destination <destination>
                          Write the image (in png format) to the provided file on the host device.

OUTPUT OPTIONS:
  -v, --verbose           If given, provide more logging output than normal.
  -q, --quiet             If given, output will include only errors.
  -t, --timeout <seconds> The overall command timeout in seconds. If this limit is exceeded the command is abandoned as a failure.
  -j, --json-output <path>
                          An optional path to write a JSON file with command results.
        Note: JSON output to a user-provided file on disk is the ONLY supported interface for scripts/programs to consume command output.
  -l, --log-output <path> An optional path to write all logging otherwise passed to stdout/stderr.

OPTIONS:
  --version               Show the version.
  -h, --help              Show help information.
```

I've tried multiple variations of parameters and both apple-bundle-id and app-path, but always receive an error.

`xcrun devicectl device info appIcon --device *** --app-bundle-id *** --app-path *** --allow-placeholder true --width 60 --height 60 --scale 3 --destination icon.png -j icon.json -t 10 -v`

With JSON output

```
  "error" : {
    "code" : 6007,
    "domain" : "com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError",
    "userInfo" : {
      "NSLocalizedDescription" : {
        "string" : "CGImage was nil when attempting to write to a destination."
      }
    }
  },
```

Without JSON output

```
09:32:42  Acquired tunnel connection to device.
09:32:42  Enabling developer disk image services.
09:32:42  Acquired usage assertion.
Application Icon Image Information
• Is Placeholder - false
• Size
    • Height - 0.0
    • Width - 0.0
• Scale - 0.0
• Pixel Size
    • Height - 0.0
    • Width - 0.0
```

How to successfully extract an app icon using devicectl?

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to:

- macOS Sonoma 14.1+
- Xcode 15.0.1+
- iOS 17.0.3

The `devicectl` command works.

However, with icons smaller than 1024x1024, the pixels are misaligned. Looks like a bug on Apple's side to me.

Comment: Can you please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com with an example?